# How can I use Botkit Middleware with Watson Assistant dialog server actions?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, botkit, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions

I followed this [tutorial to deploy a Slackbot with Watson Assistant](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html). The tutorial uses server actions in the dialog to directly interface with a database. To connect Slack with Watson Assistant the tutorial uses the Conversation connector. That works fine, but I am interested in how to do the same with Botkit and the [Botkit Middleware provided by Watson Developer Cloud](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware).

How can I use the serverless actions, how do I obtain and pass the necessary API key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually [code that demonstrates how to configure the API key for IBM Cloud Functions and pass it as context variable to Watson Assistant](https://github.com/data-henrik/botkit-watson-serveraction/). It makes use of the `before` method to add the API key to the context variable. The value is configured in a separate file together with the other app-related credentials. The code tests whether the context variable and the key exist, else it is added:

```
middleware.before = function(message, conversationPayload, callback) {
  // Code here gets executed before making the call to Conversation.

  // retrieve API Key from environment and split it into user / password
  var arr=process.env.ICF_KEY.split(":");
  // check if context exists
  if (typeof(conversationPayload.context) === 'undefined') {
      var context={context: {}}
      Object.assign(conversationPayload, context);
  }
  // if credentials already exists, we don't have to add them
  // else add credentials under private element in context
  if (typeof(conversationPayload.context.icfcreds) === 'undefined') {
     var privcontext = {"private": {icfcreds: {user: arr[0], password: arr[1]}}};
     Object.assign(conversationPayload.context, privcontext);
  }

  // log the payload structure for debugging
  // console.log(conversationPayload)
  callback(null, conversationPayload);
}
```